# Aligning captions of subfloat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have a caption alignment problem for the captions of the subfloat.
An example case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=2pt,captionskip=1pt}
\centering

\subfloat[caption 2]{
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\
    \end{minipage}

}
\subfloat[caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{There are example figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

this produces:
[image]

How can we align captions of (a) and (b) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `minipage` make a mess in images positioning (due to it baseline). Solution is use two or instead them use `tabular` as it is used in example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=2pt,captionskip=1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{b{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize]{example-image-a}}

\subfloat[caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize]{example-image-b}
\hfill
                     \includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize]{example-image-c}
}
    &
\subfloat[caption 2]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.96\hsize]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{There are example figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...and the sub-numbering starts with (b) instead of (a) ;-)

Comment: Interestingly. I didn't noted this. I need to inspect my code again ... I see, there is left one spurious `\subfloat`